# Firebase Stuck in infinite loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, firebase-realtime-database

I try to change values for all children in Firebase Database. First I try to collect the IDs, and after that, change value.

```
ref = DatabaseRef.changeUserRef
ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
        for items in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
            let itemObject = items.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let id = itemObject?["id"]
            self.ref.child(id as! String).child("status").setValue(UserStatus.userOut)
            self.ref.child(id as! String).child("inDate").setValue("0000-00-00 00:00")
        }
    }
})
```

It works well. All the values are changing as set. But I can't figure out why the app is stuck in this loop. If I try to change any value (like just rewrite in online firebase console), it changes again to UserStatus.userOut's value.

If I close the app, the loop is closed and of course I can change the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
ref.observe(DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

should be single observe

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
```